# Keras model gets constant loss and accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to train a keras CNN against the Street View House Numbers Dataset. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/asindico/digitRecognition/tree/9faa600f956e264ca61afe48d64c833f8b58711c).
The problem is that during training neither loss nor accuracy change over time. I have tried with 1 Channel (Gray Scale) images, with RGB (3 channels) images, with wider (50,50) and smaller (28,28) images, with more or less filters in the convolutional layers, with wider and smaller patches in the pooling layers, with and without dropout, with bigger and smaller batches, with smaller and bigger learning step for the optimizers, with different optimizers, ...

Still the training gets stuck to constant loss and accuracy

Here is how I prepared the data

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
train_folders = 'sv_train/train'
test_folders = 'test'
extra_folders = 'extra'
SV_IMG_SIZE = 28
SV_CHANNELS = 3
train_imsize = np.ndarray([len(train_data),2])
k = 500
sv_images = []
max_images = 20000#len(train_data)
max_digits = 5
sv_labels = np.ones([max_images, max_digits], dtype=int) * 10 # init to 10 cause it would be no digit
nboxes = [[] for i in range(max_images)]
print ("%d to load" % len(train_data))
def getBBox(i,perc):

    boxes = train_data[i]['boxes'] 
    x_min=9990
    y_min=9990
    x_max=0
    y_max=0
    for bid,b in enumerate(boxes):
        x_min = b['left'] if b['left'] <= x_min else x_min
        y_min = b['top'] if b['top'] <= y_min else y_min
        x_max = b['left']+b['width'] if  b['left']+b['width'] >= x_max else x_max
        y_max = b['top']+b['height'] if b['top']+b['height'] >= y_max else y_max

    dy = y_max-y_min
    dx = x_max-x_min
    dpy = dy*perc
    dpx = dx*perc
    nboxes[i]=[dpx,dpy,dx,dy]
    return x_min-dpx, y_min-dpy, x_max+dpx, y_max+dpy

for i in range(max_images):
    print (" \r%d" % i ,end="")
    filename = train_data[i]['filename']
    fullname = os.path.join(train_folders, filename)
    boxes = train_data[i]['boxes']
    label = [10,10,10,10,10]
    lb = len(boxes)
    if lb <= max_digits:
        im = Image.open(fullname)
        x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = getBBox(i,0.3)
        im = im.crop([x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max])
        owidth, oheight = im.size
        wr = SV_IMG_SIZE/float(owidth)
        hr = SV_IMG_SIZE/float(oheight)
        for bid,box in  enumerate(boxes):
            sv_labels[i][max_digits-lb+bid] = int(box['label'])

        box = nboxes[i]
        box[0]*=wr
        box[1]*=wr
        box[2]*=hr
        box[3]*=hr
        im = im.resize((SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        array = np.asarray(im)
        array =  array.reshape((SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_CHANNELS)).astype(np.float32)
        na = np.zeros([SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_CHANNELS],dtype=int)
        sv_images.append(array.astype(np.float32))
```

Here is the model

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

adam = Adam(lr=0.5)

model = Sequential()
x = Input((SV_IMG_SIZE, SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_CHANNELS))

y = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
y = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='valid')(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
y = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='valid')(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(512, activation='relu')(y)


digit1 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit2 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit3 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit4 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit5 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
model = Model(input=x, output=[digit1, digit2, digit3,digit4,digit5])


model.compile(optimizer=adam,
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])


sv_train_labels = [to_categorical(svt_labels[:,0]),
                   to_categorical(svt_labels[:,1]),
                   to_categorical(svt_labels[:,2]),
                   to_categorical(svt_labels[:,3]),
                   to_categorical(svt_labels[:,4])]
sv_validation_labels = [to_categorical(svv_labels[:,0]),
                        to_categorical(svv_labels[:,1]),
                        to_categorical(svv_labels[:,2]),
                        to_categorical(svv_labels[:,3]),
                        to_categorical(svv_labels[:,4])]

model.fit(sv_train, sv_train_labels, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=8,validation_data=(sv_validation, sv_validation_labels))
```

Comment: Show some code? Really, how do you want us to help you with that kind of question without a code

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have done much more than sharing some code, I have share the whole project. You only have to press the link in the question and you will find the complete Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: You should understand that there won't be many people willing to click on your link and explore a whole project to debug it :)  see section 'Help others reproduce the problem': http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are very right! I have updated the question with the portion of the code I consider relevant. I hope this will help you finding the reason of the problem

Comment: There are few suggestions (1) use only 1 softmax layer (instead of 5) with 10 output (match the number of classes) at the end `predict = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(y)`, (2) use only one `output` layer in the `model` and (3)  just call `to_categorical` once `sv_train_labels = to_categorical(sv_train_labels)`.

Comment: 1 softmax is crazy isn't it ? you would have 10^5 potential classes ...

Comment: @NassimBen now you mention it. Does this model actually trying to predict combination of 5 digits in the same time? That is indeed crazy. I would prefer to separate the digit segmentation and recognition task. My suggestion above is for single digit recognition though.

Comment: Google does it "all-in-one" : https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/42241.pdf

Comment: I am new to deep learning but as far as I know this task can be performed recognizing multiple digits at the same tike (i.e. Google paper) this basically means a CNN with several softmax (i.e.5) parallel dense layer at the end (multiple output). I have used the same model against MINST sequences of digits and it gets very good results. I can't see why the same model shows this weird behavior with the SVHN dataset.

Comment: Did you ever uncover your problem?

Answer (score 2):

As my comment above, I'd suggest to avoid training a model to predict 5 digits combination. It would be far more efficient to train the model to predict a single number. I tried to build quick example based on Keras example [cifar10_cnn.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py) on [MNIST SHVN format 2 (cropped digits)](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

# parameters
nb_epoch = 10
batch_size = 32

# load data
nb_classes = 10
train_data = sio.loadmat('train_32x32.mat')
test_data = sio.loadmat('test_32x32.mat')
X_train = train_data['X'].T / 255
X_test = test_data['X'].T / 255
y_train = to_categorical(train_data['y'] % nb_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(test_data['y'] % nb_classes)

# model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), shuffle=True)
```

Once you trained the model, train another model to [recognize/extract each number from an image](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/) using library such as [OpenCV](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python)

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this it is most of the time a wrong training set. I would recommend you to take a look at the actual images and labels you feed into the network. Additionally look at the actual colorbar of the images. This means seeing how their values are distributed. This often leads to the solution. Anyways, if you are able to map them, then so will the computer given a good learning rate.

Answer (score 0):

why are the labels for 104 : `[10 10  1 10  4]` ? I believe it should be `[10 10 1 0 4]`, no?

In my opinion : either you have a problem with the input data (the preparation might be wrong), or you have an architecture not suitable for this problem.

It is training, you can see on the notebook there is a change of loss between epoch 1 and 2. So it's not a training issue.

Comment: I have checked out the input data. It seems SVHN handles 0 as '10' so I changed the labels accordingly. Now all the labels look good. And all the images are cropped so that the number is well centered and visible. I know the second epoch shows an improvement but then it freezes. I have tried 50 epoches and remains with the same value of the second epoch.

Comment: What's with downvvoting this answer if that helps? ^^   If the network is learning over 2 epochs it means that there's nothing wrong with keras but it's more probable that your network architecture isnt good enough for this huge problem. Read the paper I've put in the comments of your question, google has a nice and quite similar approach :)