# how to fix constant accuracy and val_accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I attempted to fix it after seeing this [post][1] by adding dropout, but it didn't work. And I'm still getting consistent accuracy, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import os
os.environ['KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR'] = "/content"
!kaggle datasets download -d jakeshbohaju/brain-tumor
!unzip \*.zip -d brain_tumor_dataset 
!rm -rf yes
!rm -rf no
!rm -rf *.zip

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Input
from keras.layers import InputLayer, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions, ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from PIL.Image import open

from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import random
# %matplotlib inline

# Constants
IMAGE_DATASET = "/content/brain_tumor_dataset/Brain Tumor/Brain Tumor"
IMAGE_DATASET_RAW = '/content/brain_tumor_dataset/Brain Tumor/Brain Tumor'
WORKING_FOLDER = "/content/brain_tumor_dataset/working"
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224
EPOCHS = 100

# # Image3202
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
test_folder="/content/brain_tumor_dataset/Brain Tumor/Brain Tumor/Image100.jpg" 
img=mpimg.imread(test_folder)
print(img.size)
ax=plt.subplot(1,5,4)
# # ax.title.set_text(file)
plt.imshow(img)

# We will import the csv file containing the features and the classes of the images
cortex_df = pd.read_csv("/content/brain_tumor_dataset/Brain Tumor.csv")
cortex_df.head()

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
test_folder="/content/brain_tumor_dataset/Brain Tumor/Brain Tumor" 
for i in range(5):
    file = random.choice(os.listdir(test_folder))
    image_path= os.path.join(test_folder, file)
    img=mpimg.imread(image_path)
    ax=plt.subplot(1,5,i+1)
    ax.title.set_text(file)
    plt.imshow(img)

dataset_df = pd.DataFrame()
dataset_df["Image"] = cortex_df["Image"]
dataset_df["Class"] = cortex_df["Class"]
path_list = []
for img_path in os.listdir(IMAGE_DATASET):
    path_list.append( os.path.join(IMAGE_DATASET,img_path))
path_dict = {os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0]: x for x in path_list}
dataset_df["paths"] = cortex_df["Image"].map(path_dict.get)
dataset_df["pixels"] = dataset_df["paths"].map(lambda x:np.asarray(open(x).resize((IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH))))
dataset_df.head()

image_list = []
for i in range(len(dataset_df)):
    brain_image = dataset_df["pixels"][i].astype(np.float32)
    brain_image /= 255
    image_list.append(brain_image)
X = np.array(image_list)
print(X.shape)

y = np.array(dataset_df.Class)
#y.shape

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
print('The shape of the X_train :'+' '+str(X_train.shape))
print('The size of the X_train :'+' '+str(X_train.shape[0]))
print('The shape of the X_test :'+' '+str(X_test.shape))
print('The size of the X_test:'+' '+str(X_test.shape[0]))

def model(input_shape):
#     res_conv = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_tensor=None, input_shape=input_shape, pooling=None)
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Input(shape=input_shape))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", padding='same'))
            
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", padding='same'))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", padding='same'))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", padding='same'))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", padding='same'))
    
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))    # Never use sigmoid for binary classification
    
    return model

model = model(input_shape = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3))

model.summary()

# optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False, name="Adam",)
optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
loss_fn = BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Training the model
history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=10)


loss = history.history["loss"]
acc = history.history["accuracy"]

epoch = np.arange(EPOCHS)
plt.plot(epoch, loss)
# plt.plot(epoch, val_loss)
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.title('Training Loss')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'])

epoch = np.arange(EPOCHS)
plt.plot(epoch, acc)
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Training Accuracy');

eval_score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("Test loss:", eval_score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", eval_score[1])
```

some of Outputs

```
Epoch 70/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 0.6864 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 71/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 0.6867 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 72/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6866 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 73/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6866 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 74/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6867 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 75/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6868 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 76/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6869 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 77/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6867 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 78/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6866 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 79/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6867 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 80/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6864 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 81/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6866 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 82/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 12ms/step - loss: 0.6866 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 83/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 0.6867 - accuracy: 0.5577
Epoch 84/100
301/301 [==============================] - 4s 13ms/step - loss: 0.6867 - accuracy: 0.557
```

I tried a few other techniques, such as adding Epoch or dropout, but the accuracy remained the same?
[1]: [Keras model gets constant loss and accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453546/keras-model-gets-constant-loss-and-accuracy)

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your case is that you are using `from_logits = True` simultaneously with the `sigmoid` activation function.

The logit is the unnormalised prediction of a model; in other words, it is the prediction of the network before one applies `sigmoid` or `softmax`.

The default parameters are the following:

```
tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False, label_smoothing=0, reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO,
    name='binary_crossentropy'
)
```

If you use `from_logits=True`, then you have to change this line here:    `model.add(Dense(1)`, which in fact translates to linear activation.

Then your network will start learning.

Another suggestion would be to decrease the `learning_rate`, to an initial one of `0.0001`.